# getting current result from method inside another method

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to call a method which calls another method .. and depending on that method result i will continue with my method .. something like this:

```
void submit() async{
if (login) {
  ....
  bool result = await Login("966" + phone, _data.code);
  if (result) {
    successpage();
  } else {
    .....
  }
```

and login:

```
bool Login(String phone, String SMScode) {
http.post(baseUrl + loginURL + "?phone=" + phone + "&smsVerificationCode="+ SMScode,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }).then((response) {
final jsonResponse = json.decode(Utf8Codec().decode(response.bodyBytes));
print("LOGIN: " + jsonResponse.toString());
Map decoded = json.decode(response.body);
print(decoded['success']);
if (decoded['success']) {
  globals.token = decoded['token'];
  globals.login = true;
}else{
  globals.login = false;
}
});
return globals.login;
}
```

but this doesn't work and doesn't give me the result of the last bool i need .. how to solve this?

Comment: what does `print(decoded['success']);` prints?

Comment: @MeteHanKahraman bool .. true or false ...

Comment: the login function is not set as async

Comment: Instead of Using .then() - Use `async` - `await` Method.

Comment: @anmol.majhail how?

Comment: As Mentioned in Answer - Add word await in front http.post call -

Comment: @anmol.majhail thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asynchronous handling is incorrect in your program. Basically your `Login` function returns without waiting the http post.

The following update should work.

```
Future<bool> Login(String phone, String SMScode) async {
  final response = await http.post('$baseUrl$loginURL?phone=$phone&smsVerificationCode=$SMScode',
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'});
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(Utf8Codec().decode(response.bodyBytes));
  print("LOGIN: " + jsonResponse.toString());
  Map decoded = json.decode(response.body);
  print(decoded['success']);
  if (decoded['success']) {
    globals.token = decoded['token'];
    globals.login = true;
  } else {
    globals.login = false;
  }
  return globals.login;
}
```

Comment: i got that bodyBytes and body are not defined in Future<Response>

Comment: sorry, I forgot the `await` keyword. Answer updated.